# mapping tap interface with wifi interface

Tags: networking

Here we go..

Ubuntu 16.04LTS

1. Objective is, connect to external network through a tap interface.
2. The external network or Internet connected via Ubuntu WiFi_interface -> WiFi Router -> ISP
3. IP details are, Ubuntu WiFi IP: 192.168.1.10, GW 192.168.1.1(ADSL Router)

Now,

```
sudo tunctl -t tap0 
sudo ifconfig tap0 192.168.7.1 up 
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp12s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
```

configuration is intact but, does not help.

```
dinesh@dkubuntu:~$ ping -c 1 -I tap0 192.168.1.10
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) from 192.168.7.1 tap0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.7.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Following traces may help you guys,

```
dinesh@dkubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for dinesh: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The above trick worked earlier in different PC but failing now.
Do you guys suggest bridging also. Indeed i tried that option also, but did not work.

Appreciate if some one could help me to figure out the mystery behind the issue.

Comment: I guess packets should not be sourced from virtual interface, here tap0. However, my gns3 connects to Internet without any change in the above configuration, still it is mysterious to me. Few things I did,

Comment: Few things i did, 1. removed ufw package, 2. used "sudo iptables -t nat -v -L -n" command to monitor nat is working 3. installed iptables-persistent package. Its all set now.